# Rotate object having animations

Tags: animation

is it possible on Blender to rotate an object with its animations ?

As a proof of concept, i bought an character with animations. Then i tried to rotate the whole object and the result was strange.
I assume that it's just a bug when modeling/skinning/rigging the character but not so sure. What may cause this bug ?

[image]

Comment: I doubt very much it is a bug.  How this thing looks before you ...ed it up, and the steps you took to rotate will cast some light.

Comment: I had a similar-looking problem once, when I tried to edit a model—I think the problem may have been shape keys, but I can't remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try parenting the character rig to something else, maybe an empty or a non-printing object, that is centered right at the base of the rig. Then rotate that parent object, and everything should be good.

Actually, rigs often have a base object included. Check to see if your character's rig already has a base or handle that everything else is parented to. Then instead or rotating the whole character, just rotate the base. You should get better result.

Comment: I accepted this answer but i would like to add some precisions. I put an empty object on the very center of my object and linked it to the camera. Then rotating the empty would also rotate my camera that was my needs to have different view of the object. Thanks